# Select rows that tightly bound input date range

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a table where each row has a `TIMESTAMP` column. I have as input a start date time and an end date time. I need to select rows from this table that cover the input time range without selecting any "extra" rows.

The only thing I can think of is that I need to execute multiple queries to find the row where `m_time` < start date time ordered descending limit 1, and the row where `m_time` > end date time ordered ascending limit 1. Then query from the table for rows between those two `m_time`.

Is there a way to do it in one query?

Example data:

```
|        time_data          |
|---------------------------|
| rownum |      m_time      |
|--------|------------------|
|    1   | 2020-11-01T00:00 |
|    2   | 2020-11-01T01:00 |
|    3   | 2020-11-01T02:00 |
|    4   | 2020-11-01T03:00 |
|    5   | 2020-11-01T04:00 |
|    6   | 2020-11-01T05:00 |
```

`m_time` has a data type of `TIMESTAMP`

Given

`start_date_time` = `2020-11-01T01:58`
`end_date_time` = `2020-11-01T03:02`

Expected output would be rows 2-5

Oracle Version 19.8.0.0.0

Comment: What is your Oracle version? This has a very easy solution in Versions 12.1 and higher.

Comment: @mathguy Version 19.8.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*, 
        lag(m_time)  over(order by m_time) lag_m_time,
        lead(m_time) over(order by m_time) lead_m_time
    from time_data
) t
where (m_time <= :start_time and lead_m_time  > :start_time)
   or (m_time >= :start_time and m_time       <= :end_time)
   or (m_time >= :end_time   and lag_m_time   < :end_time)
```

I think the `where` clause could be simplified:

```
where lead_m_time > :start_time and lag_m_time < :end_time
```

Comment: Did you mean an OR somewhere, instead of AND?

Comment: @mathguy: yes, I got confused at some point... I (think I) fixed the answer now.

Comment: Cool, I've never heard of `lag` and `lead` before.

Comment: The `where` clause can indeed be simplified, but the inequalities should be non-strict.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12.1 and higher, `match_recognize` does quick work of such row pattern matching problems.

Notes - I changed your `rownum` column name, since `rownum` is a reserved keyword in Oracle. I used string data type for your dates (since that's what you seem to have), but that is a very bad practice. Make sure you always use date data type for dates. (This issue is unrelated to your question, so I left it alone.)

I simulate your sample data in the WITH clause; that is not part of the solution, it's just there for a quick test.

```
with
  time_data (rn, m_time) as (
    select 1, '2020-11-01T00:00' from dual union all
    select 2, '2020-11-01T01:00' from dual union all
    select 3, '2020-11-01T02:00' from dual union all
    select 4, '2020-11-01T03:00' from dual union all
    select 5, '2020-11-01T04:00' from dual union all
    select 6, '2020-11-01T05:00' from dual
  )
select rn, m_time
from   time_data
match_recognize(
  order by m_time
  all rows per match
  omit empty matches
  pattern (F{0,1} M* L{0,1})
  define  M as m_time between :start_time and :end_time,
          F as next(m_time) >= :start_time,
          L as prev(m_time) <= :end_time
);

RN M_TIME
-- ----------------
 2 2020-11-01T01:00
 3 2020-11-01T02:00
 4 2020-11-01T03:00
 5 2020-11-01T04:00
```

Comment: technically the column type of `m_time` is `TIMESTAMP` but for ease of reading I chose to show it as a date time formatted string.

Comment: @FGreg - the query works the same way. For my test, I used strings for the bind variables; you will use timestamps.

Comment: Looks like I'll also have to read up on `match_recognize`

Comment: @FGreg - if you need to read up on analytic functions (you said you weren't familiar with LEAD and LAG), then do that first, before match_recognize. Match_recognize is based in large part on the same concepts as analytic functions. Also, for match_recognize, it will help a lot if you are familiar with regular expressions (in a quite unexpected way - match_recognize applies the same concepts to patterns of rows, as regular expressions apply them to strings). Match_recognize takes time to learn, and then even more time to learn well, but it is 1000% worth the time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will do